# Bind DropDown List Using MVC With Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello Am Trying To Bind @Html.DropDownlist Using Stored Procedure In Mvc.... Am Getting Error Like This -

> 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name
>   'Pk_CategoryDetailID'

My Code Is

```
DataTable dttitleddl = getado.retrievedata("Exec S_CAT_POP_Data 200 , 'TITLE' , 0 , 0 , 1");

ViewBag.DDLTitle = new SelectList(dttitleddl.Rows, "Pk_CategoryDetailID", "CategoryDetailName");

 @Html.DropDownList("DDLTitle","--Select--")
```

Please Help Me Thanks In Advance ....

Comment: Please check the table whether it has the column called "Pk_CategoryDetailID"

Comment: Can you show the code for the stored procedure?

Comment: The column Pk_CategoryDetailID‌ is Correct

Comment: SELECT   Pk_CategoryDetailID , Fk_CategoryID , CategoryDetailName , Fk_OperatorID , IsDeleted ,       
       Remarks , CreatedDate , HospID   
     FROM    T_M_GeneralDetails

Comment: When you debug and hover over 'dttitleddl', go to the 'Columns', then 'Results View'. Do you see a column called Pk_CategoryDetailID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strong text**It seems that mention value field= "Pk_CategoryDetailID" not exist in your SP result. It may be **"CategoryDetailID"** Or you have to assign other column which exist in your SP output.

Comment: No It is Pk_CategoryDetailID Only In SP Result ....

Comment: Can you also put image of SP result

Comment: SELECT   Pk_CategoryDetailID , Fk_CategoryID , CategoryDetailName , Fk_OperatorID , IsDeleted ,       
       Remarks , CreatedDate , HospID   
     FROM    T_M_GeneralDetails

Comment: I need output result which you get in variable "dttitleddl"

Comment: Pk_CategoryDetailID Fk_CategoryID CategoryDetailName Fk_OperatorID IsDeleted Remarks CreatedDate HospID
803 269 MR. 1 0 Remarks 2007-09-14 15:06:13.000 1

Comment: try with :ViewBag.DDLTitle = new SelectList(dttitleddl, "Pk_CategoryDetailID", "CategoryDetailName"); Or convert table to list and then assign in selectlist